# Reduce two similar functions to avoid repetition

Tags: c

I have a project. In that one there are functions which are very similar because the difference is only the way to calculate. In one hand we use average calcul and in the other hand we use median calcul.
The functions use the same parameters, and the same code.

Here is the difference :

```
find_median(some parameters)
{
    /* some code */
    best_windows_median(same parameters);
    /* some code */
}
```

and

```
find_average(some parameters)
{
    /* some code */
    best_windows_average(some parameters);
    /* some code */
}
```

and it's the same for 2-3 functions. How can I regroup the 2 functions to one but keep the choice to use median or average ?

Comment: Pass an enum and use a switch/if

Comment: @Simon While easiest to implement that's not a great API. What would you call the function? `FindAverageOrMedian` ?

Comment: Don't bother simpliying it into one function. Just keep them separate. Usually in C++ you have function overloading for similar behaviors with different argumnts.

Comment: Can you separate the two `same code` blocks into their own functions?

Comment: @Rotem: FindCentralTendency.

Comment: Or pass a *function pointer* that points to the function to carry out the needed operation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I see you follow the principle of most astonishment.

Comment: @Rotem: It is not surprising at all to a statistician. The median and the average are both measures of central tendency, along with the mode and others. It would be just like a function `FindBall` where one of the parameters specified the color of ball to find.

Comment: @Eric Fair enough, I can see how that's reasonable in a statistics API, though would still avoid it in anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do that if you write a function which takes a parameter which is a pointer to a function.

for example :

```
`
int add (int a, int b){
return a+b;
}

int mul (int a, int b){
return a*b;
}

int function (int a, int b, int (*func) (int, int))
{
  return func(a,b);
}

int main (void){
 int x = function(4, 3, add);
 return EXIT_SUCCESS; }`
```

so this parameter "int (*func) (int, int)" is a pointer to a function, its name is func, and the function this pointer is pointing to must take 2 arguments their types must be int and it returns an int.
please be aware do not omit the parantheses surrounding the *punc, otherwise it will interpret as you wrote "(int *) func (int, int)" , this it is no pointer any more.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to achieve this, including passing a value to switch which calculation is used, and passing a function pointer (this second one is the essence of dependency-inversion, if that's of interest).

So either:

```
find_average(data parameters, avg_type) {
    same code
    switch (avg_type) {
    case AVG_MEAN:
        best_windows_mean(data parameters);
        break;
    case AVG_MEDIAN:
        best_windows_median(data parameters);
        break;
    case AVG_MODE:
        ...
    default:
        report unrecognised option;
    }
    same code;
}
```

or

```
find_average(data parameters, best_windows_function) {
    same code;
    best_windows_function(data parameters);
    same code;
}
```

Which one to use depends on whether you're comfortable with function pointers and whichever one you like best, really.

Comment: Passing a pointer to function would be closer to `type find_average (type parameters, type (*best_windows_function)(type)) { ...`, but in pseudo-code you have the principal correct.

Comment: yep, I was just following the pseudo-code style of OP

Answer (score 3):

The API complications may be hidden with friendly functions:

```
typedef enum { Median, Average } CentralTendencyMeasure;

find_median(parameters)
{
    find_general(parameters, Median);
}

find_average(parameters)
{
     find_general(parameters, Average);
}

find_general(parameters, CentralTendencyMeasure Measure)
{
    Some code...
    switch (Measure)
    {
        case Median:  best_windows_median (parameters); break;
        case Average: best_windows_average(parameters); break;
        default:      Report error.
    }
    Some code...
}
```

Expose only `find_median` and `find_average` to the client, so they do not see `CentralTendencyMeasure` or `find_general`.